# Not getting output or errors

Tags: javascript

When I run the program I'm not getting any output or errors for that matter. Program is simple I have to generate 7 seven random numbers between 0-9 and store their value in an array then for each number in the array I have to use a for loop to output each value.

```
var motto = [];

var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random()*10);

for (i = 0; i < 7; i++) { 

    motto.pop(randomNum);

}

for (i = 0; i < motto.length; i++) { 

    document.write(motto[i] + "<br>");
}
```

Comment: Did you mean `motto.push` instead of `motto.pop`?

Comment: also put the `var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random()*10);` inside of the first `for` cycle to have 7 different numbers

Comment: and **please** do not use document.write() - it's an ugly hangover from the infancy of Javascript. (try console.log(), or injecting the content into the DOM)

Answer (score 0):

The `pop()` method removes the last element from an array. Remember that `motto` is an empty array `[]` and it has no elements to pop out. To make things work here, you need to replace `pop()` with `push()`, so that you add a new entry at the end of the array. Also, since you generate numbers between `0-9` your condition inside the first for-loop should be `i <= randomNum;`. The last one is just my suggestion. Finally, your code should hopefully look like this:

```
 var motto = [];
 var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random()*10);

 for (i = 0; i <= randomNum; i++) { 
    motto.push(randomNum);
 }

 for (i = 0; i < motto.length; i++) { 
    document.write(motto[i] + "<br>");
 }
```

I hope that this solves the issue